# No tests executed in JUnit with Netbeans

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, netbeans, junit

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Netbeans 8.0.2
- JUnit 4.12

**Hi (test class)**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Hi {
    @Test
        public void hola(){
            assertTrue(true);
        }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: You are missing the scope in the dependency for junit
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Maven projekt the test classes must be in src/test/java, not src/main/java.